# Element like a PageView in android

Tags: java, android, ios, android-viewpager

I'm creating an app for both Androids and iOS. In a view, I'm using a pageView as a subview (I mean it doesn't fill all the viewController) in the iOS app.

I need to implement the same thing in Android and I don't know what element I should use.

[Here](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/12/23/swift-uipageviewcontroller-tutorial/) you have an example of a page view.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve this using **view pager**

**[ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)** Layout manager that allows the user to flip left and right through pages of data. You supply an implementation of a PagerAdapter to generate the pages that the view shows.

follow this link to implement view pager

- [link 1](http://www.journaldev.com/10096/android-viewpager-example-tutorial)
- [link 2](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)
- [link 3](http://codetheory.in/android-image-slideshow-using-viewpager-pageradapter/)
- [link 5](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2014/04/example-of-viewpager-with-custom.html)

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent in Android is a [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use a `ViewPager` with multiple fragments to get the same effect.